# Looking for a SQL Transaction Log file viewer

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging, transactions

If any of you have worked with a cool tool for viewing/querying the SQL Transaction logs, please let me know. This should show all the transactional sql statements which are committed or rolled back.

For Database files, if it has some additional graphical capabilities like showing the internal Binary Tree structure of the indexes, that will be awesome but I guess I am asking for too much huh..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is only relevant if you're talking SQL Server 2000 but RedGate produced a free tool called [SQL Log Rescue](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Log_Rescue/index.htm).
Otherwise, for SQL Server 2005 [ApexSQLLog](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.asp) from ApexSQL is the only other product I'm aware of

Comment: +1 for ApexSQL Log. Currently supports SQL Server 2012. Costs $1,499 per license.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the undocumented [DBCC LOG  command.](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/1,289483,sid87_gci1173464,00.html)

Answer (score 3):

There's a commercial product from Lumigent called "Log Explorer".  It's $995 per seat, but should cover your basic requirements.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this query :

```
Select * from ::fn_dblog(null,null)
```

or see this link : [How can I view SQL Server 2005 Transaction log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153514/how-can-i-view-sql-server-2005-transaction-log-file/19081839#19081839)

or this link : [How Do You Decode A Simple Entry in the Transaction Log?](http://sqlfascination.com/2010/02/03/how-do-you-decode-a-simple-entry-in-the-transaction-log-part-1/)

Answer (score 0):

There are some companies that produce log readers like Lumigent  and Red Gate. However they do not work with SQL server versions greater than 2000 because of meta data changes in the underlying system tables and data types, they might work if you do not use any new functionality but if you use varchar(max) XML datatype etc you are out of luck