# How can I view SQL Server 2005 Transaction log file

Tags: sql-server-2005, analysis, transaction-log

How can I view the SQL Server Transaction Log File (.trn)?

I'd like to be able to look inside the trn file at the individual transactions. Some records were deleted from a database and I need to know when, how and by who.

Thanks
Neal

Edit: I have .bak files from before and after the deletion, and .trn files from during.

Edit (2010-11-16): Discussed at length here:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1019240-357-1.aspx

Comment: Try using [ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

```
Select * from ::fn_dblog(null,null)
```

Is a virtual table over the log

Comment: can you give a little more information on what you mean here Preet? I have a .trn file - so could you start from there? Thanks

Comment: Comments didn't exist when this was written. It's now been edited.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command :

```
Select * from ::fn_dblog(null,null)
```

And for more information see this link : [How Do You Decode A Simple Entry in the Transaction Log](http://sqlfascination.com/2010/02/03/how-do-you-decode-a-simple-entry-in-the-transaction-log-part-1/)