# how to determine that my table was updated in sql server

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I have a table in sql server 2005. Yesterday an update was performed on the table and then updated back to the origional record. 
Now i want to figure out what the updated values was. At least i want to learn if it was really updated or not.
Is there someway to determine what i want from the transaction logs?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [undocumented command](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2009/04/how-to-view-transaction-log-in-sql.html):

> DBCC log ( dbname, 0|1|2|3|4 )
>
> where
>
> 0: minimum information (Default)
>
> 1: Returns info available using 0 +
> flags, tags and the log record length.
>
> 2: Returns info available using
> 1 + object, index, page ID and slot ID.
>
> 3: Maximum information about
> each operation.
>
> 4: Maximum information about each operation +
> hexadecimal dump of the current transaction log row

And read this: [Looking for a SQL Transaction Log file viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50106/looking-for-a-sql-transaction-log-file-viewer)

Comment: i receive some data when i run the command. But how can i filter these returning records to see if my table is updated on a spesific date? Is it possible?

Comment: @Fer Probably not, but you could try to have a relative time-frame. If you know an update was done in a certain date (for example a job that is executed every day) you can search for it.

Comment: i know the exact time(on yesterday at 9:19 a.m.). However, at that time there were hunderds of updates/inserts on database. So i need to run the command for a spesific table. If this is not possible, i think i will not be able to learn it.