# Is there a log in SQL Server where I can read what commands have been executed?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and need to see a list of what commands have been exectued and when. Is this possible? How can I read such log?

Comment: what do you mean " track the latest transactions"?

Comment: Mitch, why downvote? By track the latest transactions I mean I want to  see what transactions have been made. If there is some sort of log over these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicated question (I guess)

[Looking for a SQL Transaction Log file viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50106/looking-for-a-sql-transaction-log-file-viewer)

You can use third party software to read transaction logs.

- http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-log-rescue/
- http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx
- http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-sql-server/w/wiki/10586.log-reader.aspx

And if you want to audit truncate command try to audit all commands executed on your database.

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3861791/Database-Level-Auditing-with-Microsoft-SQL-Server-2008.htm

Answer (score 0):

There are some commercial products which will do this like Apex SQL Log and I think Red Gate might do one too, which give you a nice GUI to do all this but it is possible to do all this without them. That being said, if you only need to do this once then you might get away with juts downloading and using a trial version of one of these products.

[This tutorial](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3076/how-to-read-the-sql-server-database-transaction-log/) shows you how to get started extracting information from the log using T-SQL and an undocumented function called `fn_dblog`. However, the caveat here, as always with undocumented features, is that you should not rely on it in production code in case it disappears without warning, which it may. If you're just using it to investigate something and not using it on a scheduled basis or anything then you'll be fine.

There are quite a few other tutorials out there that use `fn_dblog` as well, so just have a look on your favourite search engine. It is worth readin up on this function before using it as the information it returns isn't all that straightforward.